# Uniform convergence of continuous, complex sequence

Tags: complex-analysis

Im looking for clarification on the following question.

''If each $u_n(x)$ is continuous on the closed interval [0,1], and the sequence converges uniformly on the half open interval [0,1), does {$u_n(x)$} necessarily converge uniformly on the closed interval [0,1]?''

I think that it will, because the continuity of each function will force it to converge uniformly at the end of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Let $u$ be the limit of the $u_n$ in $[0,1)$. Given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that
$$
m,n\ge N\implies|u_m(x)-u_n(x)|\le\epsilon\quad\forall x\in[0,1).
$$
Using continuity of the $u_k$, let $x\to1$ and get $|u_m(1)-u_n(1)|\le\epsilon$. This implies that $u_n(1)$ is a Cauchy sequence, and hence converges. Let $u(1)$ be its limit. All is left is to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to1}u(x)=u(1).
$$
Can you do it?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** 
Assume that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[0,1)$.

1. First prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1)$, and then prove that $f(1)$ is uniquely defined.
2. Then show that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ using the definition.